# Which activation function should be used for output layer in a regression task, provided that target variable is bound in range (0;1)?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, data-transformation, activation-function

recently i've come across this paper DOI: 10.1371/journal.pone.0061318

In short, authors tried to predict an unbound positive continuous target variable using multi layer perceptron. First, they transformed the target variable into range (0;1) using this formula:

$$
y_{transformed} = \frac{1}{1 + y^{-0.1}}
$$

and then use sigmoid as activation for the output layer (which contain only one neuron).

Is this choice legitimate? Why can they use that transformation formula even though it is different from  sigmoid function?

There is many more follow up papers using the same procedure without explaining why.

Comment: What's special to you about the (logistic) sigmoid function?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy actually it's their choice and that i don't understand why. My first thought when using a deep neural network model for regression task is that the last neuron should have no activation function (ie. an identity activation) and leave the target variable as it is. This is a new thing that i encounter and i am not sure if it is a logical choice or not? For example: why not using no activation in output layer? or why not using sigmoid function as the transformation function?